# Find derivative at point $(0,0)$ of $\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}$ along the vector $(2,3)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x)=\frac{x^2 y}{x^2+y^2}$, if $(x,y)$ different from $(0,0)$
and $f(x, y)=0$, if $(x,y)=(0,0)$. The gradient of the function is the (0,0) because both partial derivatives are both $0$, right? So all I would have to do is multiply this by the vector $(2,3)$ which would give me $0$, however, the answer is apparently $18/13$. How can this be?

Comment: Sure about that? I got $\frac{12}{13}$. Unless you meant the point $(3,2)$ instead of $(2,3)$.

Comment: I realized now that you have to calculate the limit of (f(t(2,3))-f(0,0))/t as t tend to 0, but why doesn't calculating the partial derivates and then multiplying them by the vector work?

Comment: Because $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$. For any other point from the domain of $f$, you can do it like that.

Comment: I see, thanks. Also, the vector is indeed (3,2), the expression was the thing I wrote wrong, in the numerator, the square is in the y, not the x